# What's the simplest HTML5 demo app that incorporates a broad sample of available features?

Tags: html, demo

All I know about HTML5 is that it's some type of rebranding of DHTML/Ajax with some new features like local browser databases that apps can use.

What I'm looking for is a demo app that gives a broad overview of the available features in an easy-to-digest stripped-down way before I plunge into the details.

Could someone point me to a good demo app that fits this bill?

Comment: "some type of rebranding of DHTML/Ajax"? You couldn't be more wrong.

Answer (score 0):

http://html5demos.com/ or [slides.html5rocks.com/](http://slides.html5rocks.com/)